# Is there a relationship between the Haar measure of two LC groups $G$ and $H$ and the Haar measure of their free product $G\ast H$?

Tags: operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

How categorically closed is the category of LC groups? Specifically, are there natural topologies on amalgams (or certain amalgams) of LC groups that are again locally compact?

If there are such occurrences, is there a relationship between the Haar measures of each group in a diagram and the Haar measure on the amalgamated product?

I would be interested in any literature suggestions about this.

Comment: It is the [product measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure) of the two measures ?

Comment: That would definitely be the case if the given amalgamated product was just the direct product; i.e. the images of $G$ and $H$ commuted with each other, but I think things are more complicated in general.........I could be wrong.